# Ajustar imagen a elemento background ya definido

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, xml

Estoy haciendo una sección de mi app la cual tiene como objetivo encontrar eventos presentes en mi firebase. Estos eventos son recopilados y mostrados en un listview con un formato específico, el cual quiero que sea el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en que con mi imagen de ejemplo de mi equipo funciona y sale con esta forma redonda, sin embargo con la que le paso, ubicada en firebase, ocupa todo el ancho saltándose las reglas que le he puesto. Necesito por favor que me ayudeis a que independientemente del tamaño de la imagen, esta se ajuste y se expanda si fuera necesario para que ocupe este espacio sin sobrepasarse.
(lo de la fecha ya esta resuelto pero actualmente se ve asi)

[image: actualmente aparece asi]

Mi xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/event_shape"
        android:clipToOutline="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/evento_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/evento_banner"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/event_shape">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/evento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Evento"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fechainicio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="20/10/2023"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ratingstar"
            android:text="4,7"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingstar"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_star_24" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lineaseparacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locationicon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_location_on_24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/localizacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/locationicon"
            android:text="Madrid"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fechafin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:text="27/10/2023"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/precio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:text="Gratis"
            android:textColor="#4CAF50"
            android:textSize="14sp">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

El método que carga las listas:

```
    package com.example.lude.Varios;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.lude.Cuentas.AjustesUser;
import com.example.lude.Cuentas.Evento;
import com.example.lude.Cuentas.User;
import com.example.lude.Cuentas.Valoraciones;
import com.example.lude.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class AdaptadorListasEvento extends ArrayAdapter<Evento> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Evento> mEventos = null;
    private int layoutResource;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Valoraciones> valoraciones;


    public AdaptadorListasEvento(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Evento> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutResource = resource;
        mContext = context;
        this.mEventos = objects;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView bannerimage;
        TextView evento, localizacion, fechainicio, fechafin, mediavaloraciones, precio;

        RelativeLayout relLayout1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.relLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relLayout1);

            holder.bannerimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.evento_banner);
            holder.evento = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.evento);
            holder.localizacion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.localizacion);
            holder.fechainicio = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fechainicio);
            holder.fechafin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fechafin);
            holder.precio = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.precio);
            holder.mediavaloraciones = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(mContext);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
        imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getBanner_link(), holder.bannerimage);
        holder.relLayout1.setClipToOutline(true);
        holder.evento.setText(getItem(position).getNombre());
        holder.localizacion.setText(getItem(position).getLocalizacion());
        holder.fechainicio.setText(getItem(position).getFecha_inicio());
        holder.fechafin.setText(getItem(position).getFecha_fin());
        holder.precio.setText(getItem(position).getPrecio());
        valoraciones = getItem(position).getValoraciones();
        holder.mediavaloraciones.setText(String.valueOf(getMediaValoraciones(valoraciones)));

        return convertView;
    }

    private int getMediaValoraciones(ArrayList<Valoraciones> valoraciones) {
        int media = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < valoraciones.size(); i++) {
            media += Integer.parseInt(valoraciones.get(i).getValoracion());
        }
        return media / valoraciones.size();
    }
}
```